# Centering a div which has an image overlayed on top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container div with an image overlayed on top of it.

I want to center this container div within a basic popin.  I am sure it has something to do with the overlay approach I am using within the CSS, but I cannot figure it out.  How can I center the container dev within the popin?

EDIT:  There are several of these blocks placed in-line.

CSS and HTML are as follows:

```css
.containerdiv { float: left; position: relative; } 
.cornerimage { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }

.popin{
  background:#fff;
  padding:15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #999;
  border-radius:2px;
}

#underlay1 {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  position: relative;
}

#underlay2 {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 popin">
    <div class="containerdiv">
      <div id="underlay1"></div>
      <img class="cornerimage" border="0" src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320" alt="">  
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 popin">
    <div class="containerdiv">
      <div id="underlay2"></div>
      <img class="cornerimage" border="0" src="http://lorempixel.com/320/320" alt="">  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Underlay is receiving an image from an API.  overlayimage.gif is another image being placed on top.

Comment: Can you please show an example of the code using jsfiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `float: left;` from `.containerdiv` and give `text-align: center;` to `.popin` will solve your issue.

You can center absolute div like following way:

```
left: 50%; 
transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5z2k1b1r/

**Edit:**

use     `margin: 0 auto;` for `#underlay` as per your expected output.

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5z2k1b1r/3/)

Comment: This throws off the positioning of the overlay image.  BTW, I've included a few more details.  This applies to multiple divs inline within the "row".

Comment: This still throws off the image overlay.  The div "underlay1" is receiving an image from google maps.  I am overlaying another image on top within div "cornerimage".  With your solution, the 2 get out of alignment.

Comment: Seems closer.. but the overlayed image is still off.  I wonder if it has something to do with the image being received into #underlay.  The size of the inbound image is 300x300 px.

Comment: ah yes, reduced #overlay to match at 300x300 and I think it worked. reviewing